# Integral$\int_0^\infty \ln x\,\exp(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}) \frac{x^4+\alpha x^2- 1}{x^4}dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove
$$
I:=\int_0^\infty \ln x\,\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) \frac{x^4+\alpha x^2- 1}{x^4}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2\alpha^3 \pi}}{2\sqrt[\alpha]e},\qquad \alpha>0.
$$

Note: The proof below shows how this is just a Gaussian integral!

I am not sure how to start this one.  It seems very difficult to me However the answer is very nice.

I thought maybe trying to write $I(\alpha)$ and $I'(\alpha)$ to try and simplify things but it didn't help much.  at $x=0$ there seems to be a problem with the integrand also however I am not sure how to go about using this.  Perhaps we could try and use a series expansion for $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n / n!$ however the function $e^{-1/x^2}$ is well known that its taylor series is zero despite the function not being. The factor of $x^4+\alpha x^2-1$ has been giving me trouble with simplifying the integrand.  Thanks.

To those who just made an edit:  If you are looking for a +2, please edit something worthwhile.  I edited it back to what I had considering you didn't fix anything as is shown in the Edit History.

Comment: Is $a=\alpha {}$?

Comment: Okay, how was this problem constructed? Perhaps this could give us insight into how to solve the problem. I doubt the right approach is contour integration despite the $\sqrt{\pi}$ and I think it will involve the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you I fixed it.  $\alpha$

Comment: @ChrisK Yes I was thinking contour integration but wasn't sure of how to go about that, it seems tough that way.  Thanks!.  What do you mean how was this constructed?  This is a definite integral that I saw years ago and I still have.  It is not from another problem, or any kind of engineering/physics application.  It is an integral that came from a list of many other integrals.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I see no one has answered yet. Maybe I should get out some paper and work on it?

Comment: @ChrisK This integral is rather nice.  I have many variations of this too with miraculous closed forms!  Thank you.  If you do provide a solution even better:) Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please *always* include some English words in the title, so that on right-clicking it, the usual context menu will not be overridden by MathJax's menu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^\infty \ln x\,\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) \frac{x^4+\alpha x^2- 1}{x^4}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \ln x\, d\left(-\alpha x^{-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)\right)\\
&=-\alpha\left(\left.\frac{\ln x}{x}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)\right|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) d\,\ln x\right)\\
&=\alpha\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) dx\\
&=\alpha\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx+\underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx}_{x\to1/x}\right) \\
&=\alpha\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx+\int_1^0 -\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx\right) \\
&=\alpha\int_0^1 (1+\frac{1}{x^2})\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\alpha\int_0^1 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{(x-1/x)^2}{2\alpha }\right)d(x-1/x)\\
&=\alpha e^{-1/\alpha}\int_0^1 \exp\left(-\frac{(x-1/x)^2}{2\alpha }\right)d(x-1/x)\\
&=\alpha e^{-1/\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^0 \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\alpha }\right)dy\\
&=\alpha e^{-1/\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha\pi}{2}}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You are very good Chen Wang.  Thank you for your solution again.  +1

Comment: I am still very impressed you reduced this to just a Gaussian integral.  This is a very deep solution you have produced.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{I\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}
     \exp\pars{-\,{1 + x^{4} \over 2\alpha x^{2}}}\,
     {x^4+\alpha x^2- 1 \over x^4}\,\dd x=
     {\root{2\alpha^{3}\pi} \over 2\root[\alpha]{\expo{}}}:\ {\large ?},
     \qquad \alpha > 0}$.

> From [@Chen Wang answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/779407/85343) $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{line}\ 4~}}$:
>   $$
> I=\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over x^{2}}
> \exp\pars{-\,{1 + x^{4} \over 2\alpha x^{2}}}\,\dd x
> $$

With $\ds{\expo{\theta} = x}$:
\begin{align}
I&=\alpha\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-2\theta}
\exp\pars{-\,{\cosh\pars{2\theta} \over \alpha}}\,\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
=2\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty}\cosh\pars{\theta}
\exp\pars{-\,{\cosh\pars{2\theta} \over \alpha}}\,\dd\theta
\end{align}

> Since
>   $\ds{\cosh\pars{2\theta} = \cosh^{2}\pars{\theta} + \sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}
> = 2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}$ and
>   $\ds{\totald{\sinh\pars{\theta}}{\theta} = \cos\pars{\theta}}$ we'll have:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#44f}{\large I}&=
> 2\alpha\expo{-1/\alpha}\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\cosh\pars{\theta}
> \exp\pars{-\,{2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} \over \alpha}}\,\dd\theta}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{Lets}\ u\ \equiv\ \sinh\pars{\theta}}}
> ={2\alpha \over \root[\alpha]{\expo{}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-2u^{2}/\alpha}
> \,\dd u
> \\[3mm]&={2\alpha \over \root[\alpha]{\expo{}}}\,\root{\alpha \over 2}\
> \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-u^{2}}\,\dd u}_{\ds{=\ {\root{\pi} \over 2}}}
> =\color{#44f}{\large{\root{2\alpha^{3}\pi} \over 2\root[\alpha]{\expo{}}}}
> \end{align}